# Retrieve Example data present in Jackrabbit Database in BI Platform Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

In Pentaho Bi-server i m using Mysql as Repository database and as per Pentaho documentation all the example files would be present in Jackrabbit database
so can anyone please tell me how to retrieve the example data present in jackrabbit database. and is their any method to reconfirm whether its connected to
Mysql database or default Hsql database.

Thanks in advance and if anyone knows the solution please do reply as i m not finding any relevant documents for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use mysql as a repository database - most probably you have edit the

```
biserver-ee\pentaho-solutions\system\jackrabbit\repository.xml
```

all examples by default is in default jackrabbit store - in current version by default bi-server uses file-based jackrabbit implementation. Means it is uses local file system and examples accessible locally.

After some-one have edit repository.xml file to point to a real database to be served as jackrabbit store - initially it is empty.

Pentaho examples is some reports as far as data store called 'sampledata'. Reports is is jackrabbit repository. Data for reports is in HSQLDB, which is typically started with bi-server together. All the simple data as far as SQL create/load scripts located at

```
biserver-ee\data\hsqldb
```

directory, for example database creation script is sampledata.script.

The question is how to get reports from default jackrabbit repository in mysql repository is the question how to export and then import items from one to another repository implementations. The question where to obtain sampledata is how to start HSQLDB from folder I mention above. Hope it will help.